# Why is json not shown in Mercurial's template list?

Tags: mercurial

`hg log --template list` shows `available styles: bisect, changelog, compact, default, phases, status, xml`, but not `json`.

Yet `hg log --template json` works fine.

Why is `json` not shown in the the list?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, just because now json-style is dirty hack. Template list lists all styles for files with

- predefined name pattern `map-cmdline.STYLE`
- in predefined location %THG%\templates

(see my `dir` output and list of styles, note custom`colorlog` style)

```
TortoiseHg\templates>dir /B
...
map-cmdline.bisect
map-cmdline.changelog
map-cmdline.colorlog
map-cmdline.compact
map-cmdline.default
map-cmdline.phases
map-cmdline.status
map-cmdline.xml
...

>hg log -T list
available styles: bisect, changelog, colorlog, compact, default, phases, status, xml
```

but yes, I *can* also use `-T json`

Comment: [Apparently](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2013-September/053610.html) there is/was a plan that is makes json more generic than  `add map-cmdline.json` would have been, so it's not a dirty hack?